# Using as.data.table, getting error "cannot coerce class ""integer64"" to a data.frame"

Tags: r, data.table, r-sp

I have a column of parcel identifier numbers which `data.table::fread` reads in as integer64. It was throwing errors some months ago so I was converting to character, but after it stopped throwing errors I saw no downside to leaving it as it was. But after some processing with package sp, I was trying to revert from SpatialPointsDataFrame back to data.table with `x <- as.data.table(x)` and got:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""integer64"" to a data.frame
```

Reading in as character is the consensus recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171760/in-r-is-it-better-to-use-integer64-numeric-or-character-for-large-integer-id-n#35172059). But I am trying to understand what's going on. They could have been numbers not IDs. Seems like `sp::coordinates` is able to take in integer64 numbers from a data.table into its own type of data frame but from there on it's a one-way street?

EDIT: I was going to do `traceback()` etc. suggested by @MichaelChirico in the comments, realized R was hanging after the error message, decided to try on a small sample. To my surprise it worked with no errors/warnings. So far, the largest single table to which I added spatial data and converted back had circa 2.25 million rows. I kept upping the sample size to see where it would break. The end result was (to me) twilight zone - I was able to convert the whole SPDF if I randomized the rows, not if not!
https://imgur.com/aghsdDA  This is not a "solution" so I'm going to leave this up here for someone who knows what's going on under the hood.

EDIT_2: Replaced inline illustrative image in previous edit with a link. Link to 12MB SPDF file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZTCIT3BBFqZMHWhHrxeKzLUlDupsm_vm/view?usp=sharing). Variable of interest is integer64 'Prop'- see above; trying to revert from SPDF back to data.table. Reproducible on my Mac 10.10.5, running Rstudio v1.1.453 on R v3.3.3, packages data.table v1.10.4-3 and sp v1.3-1. Substitute PATH_TO_FILE with your download location below:

`x <- readRDS("PATH_TO_FILE/x_SPDF.rds")`

```
z <- x[sample(nrow(x), 2535323),] # all rows but randomized
z <- as.data.table(z) # works
x1 <- x[1:2535322, ] # un-randomized subset w/ nrow() minus 1
x1 <- as.data.table(x1) # works
x <- as.data.table(x) # stops with error noted in initial question
```

Being on an old clunker of a Mac may have something to do with it, but I figure if it works on subsets and randomized subsets of any size, it should work generally.

Comment: Easiest may be to install & load the `bit64` package, I guess

Comment: for why you're experiencing this particular error, maybe try examining the `traceback()` and/or `debugonce(as.data.frame.default)` or `debugonce(as.data.table)`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Further, please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.